# Flutter : How to save widget to png with transparent background?

Tags: flutter

There is the way to save the widget into transparent png and save it into gallery?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Flutter draws every single pixel, so you can easily convert your widget to an image.

You need to follow these steps:

**Edit** -- first import [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider/install) link to pupspec.yaml and then follow this steps

1. Create a `GlobalKey`

   ```
   final _globalKey = GlobalKey();
   ```
2. Create `Uint8List`

   ```
   Uint8List pngBytes;
   ```
3. Wrap your widget with `RepaintBoundary` widget & pass in the key

   ```
   RepaintBoundary(
     key: _globalKey,
     child: YourWidget(),
   ),
   ```
4. Create a method to convert your widget to image:

   ```
   Future<void> _capturePng() async {
     try {
       final RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
           _globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
       final image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 2.0); // image quality
       final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
       pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
     } catch (e) {
       print(e);
     }
   }
   ```
5. Convert your image to a file so that you can save it in your app

   ```
   Future<File> convertImageToFile(Uint8List image) async {
     final file = File(
         '${(await 
        getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png');
     await file.writeAsBytes(image);

     return file;
   }
   ```

Comment: thank u for your reply,
i got error on step 5, any solution?

Comment: "The getter 'png' isn't defined for the type 'Ser<int'."
But its ok, I managed to save it with 'image_gallery_saver' package. But I got antoher problem, the package is not perfect, when i use the saveImage method i cannt save my image into png, the image always save in jpeg format, when I use the saveFile method, the file generating its name its self. Now i need to search how to rename the exiting file. Thank in advance Sir.

Comment: Welcome! If you find this answer useful, you can mark it as accepted and upvote it also. Happy to help. (Ps, no need to call me Sir)